# Substracting number from list not raising TypeError

Tags: python, list, numpy, array-broadcasting

If I do

```
a = [1, 2, 7]
a - a[-1]
```

I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'`

However, I have a list `b` made of `np.float64`, and the following code works:

```
type(b)
# list
b - b[-1]
# array([ 281.04209146,    6.57013103,    0.        ])
```

I think this is because the numbers in `b` are `np.float64`, and `b` is somewhat cast to `np.array`, then broadcasting happens.
But I still found this behavior surprising: since all elements in a list do not need to have the same type, what if `b[0]` had been a string ? The operands in  `b - b[-1]` would still have been `list` and `np.float64`, so why is `b - b[-1]` not raising a `TypeError`?

**EDIT**: Someone answered saying that `list` and `np.array` are different; well, I know. But there `b` is not a `np.array`. It is *behaving* like one, but its type is `list`, like I've stated in the code snippet.

Here's a minimal working example for `b`:

```
b
# [1598.717274996219, 1324.245314569733, 1317.6751835362861]
type(b[0])
# numpy.float64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an expression like `A-B`, the interpreter can either implement it as `A.__sub__(B)` or `B.__rsub__(A)`.

Lists implement `mul` and `add` but not `sub`

```
In [29]: [1,2,3]*3
Out[29]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
In [30]: [1,2,3]+[1]
Out[30]: [1, 2, 3, 1]
In [31]: [1,2,3]-3
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

`np.ndarray` implements a `__rsub__`

```
In [32]: [1,2,3]-np.array([1,2,3])
Out[32]: array([0, 0, 0])
# np.array([1,2,3]).__rsub__([1,2,3])
```

And that method tries to turn the LHS into an array, so this expression is the same as:

```
In [33]: np.asarray([1,2,3]) - np.array([1,2,3])
Out[33]: array([0, 0, 0])
```

If the list contains strings, this fails:

```
In [35]: ['a',2,3]-np.array([1,2,3])
TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U11') dtype('<U11') dtype('<U11')
```

because that list becomes an array of strings:

```
In [36]: np.asarray(['a',2,3])
Out[36]: 
array(['a', '2', '3'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

and array subtraction with string dtype is not implemented.

All that I wrote with the array RHS applies if it is `np.float64`.  `np.float64(10)` behaves (in most contexts) the same as `np.array(10.0)`.

So all these subtractions with `b` are the same:

```
 b = [np.float64(10), np.float64(1)]
 b - b[-1]
 b - np.float64(1)
 b - np.array(1.0)
 np.array(b) - np.array(1.0)
```

In sum, if the RHS is some sort of array, it turns the LHS list into an array as well.  From there it's a question of whether the 2 arrays are compatible (in shape and dtype).

Answer (score 1):

You don't get the same `TypeError` when you make `b[0]` a string though.

```
b=[np.float_(a_) for a_ in a]

b
Out[4]: [1.0, 2.0, 7.0]

b-b[-1]
Out[5]: array([-6., -5.,  0.])

b[0]='a'

b
Out[7]: ['a', 2.0, 7.0]

b-b[-1]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<#>", line 1, in <module>
    b-b[-1]

TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

You get a `TypeError` for mismatching types in `subtract`.  In the original, when you get a `np.float64` for `b[-1]`, it casts the whole expression to numpy arrays.  So if `b[-1]` is a string:

```
b[2]='a'

b-b[-1]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<#>", line 1, in <module>
    b-b[-1]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'str'
```

you're back to the original `TypeError`.

Comment: Yes, I've tested that behavior as well. Sorry if I was not clear, my question is rather "why doesn't `list - np.float`  systematically raises an error ?".

Comment: Numpy is 'helpful' (or greedy, if it's unwanted).  If it's used anywhere in an expression, it tries to be everywhere.  So if you do `[1,2,3]-np.array([1,2,3])` you will get `np.array([0,0,0])`

Comment: Ok, so could you clarify `it tries'? What are the checks it performs ?

Comment: An `np.float` has many of the same methods as an `np.ndarray`.

Comment: Not a dev, but I'd imagine by wrapping any non-numpy objects in `numpy.asarray`.  Which is why the list with one string in it gets cast to an array of all strings: `np.asarray(['a',2,3])` -> `array(['a', '2', '3'], dtype='<U1')`, which can be seen in the first error above